# Display multiple images in contenteditable div

Tags: php, file-upload, contenteditable

Users are able to upload an image and it will be inserted into a contenteditable div.

When the user uploads one image, the page refreshes and the image is displayed in the contenteditable div. When they then add another image, the first one is automatically removed.

How do I display all images, without removing an image when another one is uploaded?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$ImageName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'photo';
$path = '../photos/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['photo']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $location); 
header('Location: newpost.php?img='.$location);
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="document.getElementById('upload').click();" id="file" class="inputfile" />
<input type="submit" style="display: none;" name="upload" id="upload">
<div id="post" contenteditable>
if(!empty($_GET['img'])) {
echo'<img src="'.$_GET['img'].'" class="image" />';
}
?>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: where is your `action="....php"`? I can't see it in your form.

Comment: @AndreChenier I didn't think that my form needed an action as the PHP script is on the same page as it.

Comment: I would. And I also would use a $_SESSION array in the div where user uploaded images are supposed to be shown. PHP is stateless so one needs sessions or MySQL transactions to remember the past.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use session variable.

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$ImageName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'photo';
$path = '../photos/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['photo']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $location); 

$imageArray = array(); 
if (isset($_SESSION['images'])){
$imageArray = $_SESSION['images']; 
}
array_push($imageArray,$location); 
header('Location: newpost.php?img='.$location);
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="document.getElementById('upload').click();" id="file" class="inputfile" />
<input type="submit" style="display: none;" name="upload" id="upload">
<div id="post" contenteditable>

if(isset($_SESSION['images'])) {
foreach($_SESSION['images'] as $image){
echo'<img src="'.$image .'" class="image" />';
}
}


?>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The image is no longer being shown in the contenteditable div once it's been uploaded.

Comment: That's what saving it to session does. It saves the images so when your page refreshes your session will have the array of image locations so you can load all of them. Isn't that what you want ?

Comment: The images aren't being loaded _(I can't seem them)_

Comment: add this to the top of your php to see if you are getting any errors. Also you have to upload first after changing the code.             `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`